# C# Windows Service: Having multiple service in a project with different security context installation

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have requirement to run 2 different services ServiceA & ServiceB under a single windows service project* (ProjectA). Trick or where I got stuck is that I want to install these 2 services with 2 different security context like ServiceA runs under Local System and ServiceB runs should run under Network Service.

I understand we will have 1 ProjectInstaller for entire service. And for each Service we'll have separate ServiceInstaller classes, however the ServiceProcessInstaller where we set security context will always be one per project? Can anyone help tell how to supply different security context for differnet Service?

*Please note: Both Services runs under single assembly

Comment: You likely really want to rethink your design.  In general, security is set at the process level in Windows.  You can _Impersonate_ (see `WindowsImpersonationContext`) within the context of a thread, but it will drastically complicate your code and open the door to security bugs.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to tell what sort of security bugs it may lead to? Also, Ill change the design to have individual exe/assembly per service to move on.